# Dropbox SDK cannot be imported?

Tags: python, django, dropbox

I've encountering this strange issue with Dropbox SDK when I am importing it. On the server I get the error message

```
ImportError at /supplier/
No module named client
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/supplier/
Django Version: 1.7.7
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named client
Exception Location: /home/yonk/projects/apple/supplier/dropbox_adapter.py in <module>, line 3
Python Executable:  /home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/yonk/projects/apple',
 '/home/yonk/Desktop/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.9.2.201502050007/pysrc',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/yonk/projects/apple/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old']
Server time:    Sun, 5 Apr 2015 17:51:22 +0000
```

My `view.py` file looks like this, only one line to try and import the SDK

```
import dropbox
#EOF
```

Attempts so far:

- Remove the line `import dropbox` and error disappears, but that
  defeats the purpose
- In `./manage shell` and I was able to import dropbox no problem.
- reinstalling dropbox via pip, problem persists
- run in `./manage runserver` as well as via a WSGI server. Both yield
  the same error.
- Import a different third party module such as django-facebook, no
  error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. I forgot to run Migrate. Amateur mistake. Won't make again.